# Transition to .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 from .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

WPF and WCF developer.   Write business applications and UI is pretty basic. Want to go to 4.5 for parallel processing ease and features.

Typically on a new release of Visual Studio I will read one book on WPF and one on .NET.
Have my favorite author on each.

And this point I get impression the UI side .NET 4.5 is not really different from 4.0.
I have seen nothing about a new UI control in 4.5.

Do I need to read a book on WPF 4.5?   Has the UI changed enough to justify a refresh?

Already a close vote and I get (and accept) it.
Should I open another question on are there any new UI controls in 4.5 from 4.0?

Comment: If you changed your question I would still have voted to close.

Comment: @JohnSaunders cool. Is there another site I should post this on?

Comment: Your question is just too vague for [so]. If you had a specific problem, then we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few useful improvements and new features related with databases in WPF 4.5.

There is a "Ribbon" control.

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588.aspx

Read some documentation about new objects and properties. You dont need whole book.